# Wordpress sidebar column pushed down following the main column

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress blog, and the problem I am having is that the sidebar of the blog is being pushed down after the main column for the content of each post. The theme is Papercut and the PHP for each post is singe.php

http://www.mirabaz.com/wordpress/articles/cnn-ireport-features-sanaa-music-festival/

This is the home page http://www.mirabaz.com. As you can see the sidebar has to on right side of the page.

If i remove the code the shoes the content of the post, then it the sidebar comes back to the original position. But the content is blank.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You have an out of place and extra `<div class="footer">` tag right below `<body>` in your index.php or header.php file, and that looks for a `</div>` closing tag, and both are throwing your sidebar out of place. You can see it in your W3C code validation report: 
[[Invalid]Markup Validation of   mirabaz.com wordpress  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.mirabaz.com/wordpress/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Some of the code erros don't effect display, but the `<div>` errors will.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your #right-col is inside the #left-col, when they should be at the same level. Check your closing div tags as this is probably the issue.

Hope this helps,
Alin

Comment: I have checked the <div> and it is outside within '<div id="content" class="clearfix">' tags

Comment: I added another closing div after the left-col closing comment and the sidebar moved back up. This proves that you have an unclosed element. You should try to locate the problem (you can probably find it inside your article, not the theme). I recommend using validator.w3.org to check your HTML (you will find that you have other problems as well).